# pythonまたはRで共分散構造分析をする際、2値データを扱う方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, r

アンケートデータを使って共分散構造分析を行いたいのですが、回答がはい/いいえの2値の場合、テトラコリック相関を使う、という情報にたどり着きました。
pythonかRの共分散構造分析用ライブラリ（手元ではsemopyを試しています）で、2値データを使って分析を行う場合、どのようにコードを書けばよいでしょうか。

Comment: 私の専門としていた分野ではないため、詳しいことはお伝えできませんが、質問の改善をした方がよいと思いましたので、コメントします。
図などを作成し、何を分析したいのか、仮定は何を置いているのか追加情報がないとヒントとなるコードは得られない気がします。
下記URLで説明されている図を参考にすると回答が得られるかもしれません。
https://www.nttcoms.com/service/research/dataanalysis/sem/

Comment: 余計なお世話かもしれませんが、元のデータがテキストの場合、0、1の変数に変えた方が望ましいです。今回の場合は、「いいえ」が0、「はい」が1ですかね。ただし、アンケートの設問内容や仮説によっては、この限りではありません。